# Indexing into an array to read data (C...pretty basic question I think)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Im new to C so excuse my ignorance if this is easy. I have looked around for solutions to no avail. Also, this is in the scope of a very large program, so I will try to include only necessary code.

Here is my function:

```
void drawImage3(int x, int y, int width, int height, const u16* image)
{
    int w;
    for (w=0; r<width; w++)
    {   
        image;
        DMA[3].src = image;
        DMA[3].dst = &videoBuffer[OFFSET(x+width, y, 240)];
        DMA[3].cnt = width | DMA_SOURCE_FIXED| DMA_ON | DMA_DESTINATION_INCREMENT; 
    }
}
```

These are defined elsewhere:

```
extern unsigned short *videoBuffer;
const unsigned short *pt;
```

And image is the name of an array of shorts. It has 1024 elements. I know this code has a lot of things going on with DMA and such but the basic SYNTATICAL question is this:

On the first iteration I want
to draw `image[0]`, then `image[width]`, then `image[2*width]`, then `image[3*width]`, etc... How can I change this code so on each for loop cycle, I get those elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On the first iteration I want to draw image[0], then image[width], then image[2*width] then image[3*width], etc...

```
for (unsigned i=0; i<N; i++)
    draw(image[i*width]);
```